# show that there exist $n$ such that $r|\binom{p^n}{q^n}$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Cross-Posted from [Math Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2475002/show-that-there-exist-n-such-that-r-binompnqn)

Two positive integers $p,q$ and a prime $r$ are given, such that $r>p>q>1$.
 I have to show that there exist $n$ such that
$$r|\binom{p^n}{q^n}$$

Should I use Lucas' theorem? I can't solve it.

Comment: May I ask for what purpose do you need it?

Comment: zhoraster's answer on MSE shows that a natural approach doesn't work: There doesn't have to be a carry in the units digit. If $r=31, p=7, q=4$, then the units digit of $7^n$ is always at least the units digit of $4^n$ base $31$.

Comment: There are no counterexamples among the first 200 primes.  For $(p,q,r)=(2,669,1021)$ we need to go to $n=24$.

Comment: Didn't Zhoraster's most recent edit answer the problem completely?

Comment: Imo it is a bad way to cross-post. Firstly, the question were posted here just after the bounty on math.SE had started. You certainly should have waited for the bounty to expire. Secondly, you didn't acknowledge the cross-posting and didn't mention the reasons for it in you post on math.SE. Thirdly, you also started a bounty here, while the one on math.SE was active. You didn't commented on my answer yet, and you didn't acknowledge here that the answer is available. And so on.

Comment: Moreover, the bounty here had started **after** I wrote a comment (which I later deleted as no longer relevant) to your post on math.SE stating that I have a solution (possibly, partial), which I would post soon (and I done so in a couple of hours). What are your reasons for such misbehavior on both sites?